# Magento 2: How can i change page layout using Block file

Tags: magento2

I need to change search page layout 1-column while Search page is empty.
any idea please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can update the page layout for empty result page by observing `controller_action_layout_render_before` event in your custom module as below.

> app/code/{Namespace}/{Module}/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_layout_render_before">
        <observer name="layout_render_before" instance="{Namespace}\{Module}\Observer\LayoutRenderBefore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/{Namespace}/{Module}/Observer/LayoutRenderBefore.php

```
<?php
namespace {Namespace}\{Module}\Observer;

class LayoutRenderBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('search.result');

        if ($block instanceof \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result && !$block->getResultCount()) {
            $pageConfig = $resultPage->getConfig();
             $pageConfig->setPageLayout('1column');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help.

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked for you.

Comment: Using above codes selected attribute result showing two times in left panel. Any idea bout this.

Comment: Below line is affect for that : $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();